# Geometric equivalence of cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

Cross product is usually defined such that
$$\lVert\bf{a} \times \bf{b} \rVert =\lVert \mathbf{a}\rVert \cdot\lVert \mathbf{b} \rVert \sin\theta$$
where the result vector is perpendicular to both $a$ and $b$, with a direction given by the right-hand rule.

However, I am looking for an explanation of the following equivalence of the cross product, which states ( in *Computer Vision Algorithms and Applications, p.310*) that:

> The cross-product operator projects a vector onto a set of orthogonal
>   basis vectors that include $\hat{t}$, zeros out the $\hat{t}$ component, and rotates the other two by 90◦
>   $$[\hat{\bf{t}}]_\times =
> \bf{SZR_{90\circ}S}^T =
> \begin{bmatrix} \bf{s_0} & \bf{s_1} & \bf{\hat{\bf{t}}}\\ \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix} 1&& \\ &1& \\ &&0 \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix} 0&-1& \\ 1&0& \\ &&1 \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix} \bf{s}^T_0 \\ \bf{s}^T_1 \\ \hat{\bf{t}}^T\\ \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   where $\hat{\bf{t}} = \bf{s_0}\times\bf{s_1}$

Why is this the case?

---

Note:

$[\hat{\bf{t}}]_\times$ is the matrix form of the cross product operator with $\hat{\bf{t}} = (\hat{t}_x, \hat{t}_y, \hat{t}_z),$
$$[\hat{\bf{t}}]_\times =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -\hat{t}_z & \hat{t}_y \\
\hat{t}_z & 0 & -\hat{t}_x \\
-\hat{t}_y & \hat{t}_x & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Think about the geometric relationship of $t\times v$ to $t$ and $v$, in particular, that it’s orthogonal to them both. The slightly tricky bit is setting the lengths of $s_0$ and $s_1$ correctly.

Comment: @celtschk, I fixed it